# What topics are necessary to process with ROS to manage SLAM with Kinect

Tags: slam, navigation, odometry, kinect, rosjava

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am trying to learn how to use ROS Navigation stack and I would like to know what kind of topics are necessary to publish on ROS Core to use SLAM features with ROS using a Kinect.

Many thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12709/what-topics-are-necessary-to-process-with-ros-to-manage-slam-with-kinect/) by [Juan Antonio Breña Moral](https://answers.ros.org/users/464/juan-antonio-bre%C3%B1a-moral/) on ROS Answers with karma: 274 on 2012-01-21

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I assume you want to use the [gmapping](http://ros.org/wiki/gmapping) package in ROS to do the mapping. gmapping requires odometry of your robot. You can follow [this](http://www.ros.org/wiki/navigation/Tutorials/RobotSetup/Odom) tutorial to check out how to do that.

You also need to convert the PointCloud2 of the kinect to a LaserScan, since that is what gmapping uses. To do this you can use the [pointcloud_to_laserscan package](http://www.ros.org/wiki/pointcloud_to_laserscan).

Once you got those 2 things setup, you should be ready to use gmapping. Let me know if you got further questions.

EDIT: Forgot to mention, you need a transform link from your kinect frame to base_link. Basically base_link is the position of your robot and kinect frame is the position of your kinect. You need to define the relation between these two with a transform. You can use the static transform publisher for this, as following :

```
<node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="base_to_kinect" args="0 0 0 0 0 0 base_link kinect_depth_frame 100" />
```

That is basically the difference in xyz and the difference in orientation between the base of your robot and the kinect. For more information on the static_transform_publisher, check [here](http://ros.org/wiki/tf#static_transform_publisher).

---

Originally posted by [Hansg91](https://answers.ros.org/users/1621/hansg91/) with karma: 1909 on 2012-01-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Juan Antonio Breña Moral](https://answers.ros.org/users/464/juan-antonio-bre%C3%B1a-moral/) on 2012-01-24**:
I have to read odometry tutorial again. Many thanks.

**Comment by [Hansg91](https://answers.ros.org/users/1621/hansg91/) on 2012-01-22**:
Actually, the odometry tutorial also publishes tf messages, so that should be enough. I did forget to tell you something and I edited my answer with extra info.

**Comment by [Juan Antonio Breña Moral](https://answers.ros.org/users/464/juan-antonio-bre%C3%B1a-moral/) on 2012-01-22**:
I read in the tutotial about navigation stack: http://www.ros.org/wiki/navigation that it is necessary to use tf messages but you didn't say anithing about it. Tell me your experince

**Comment by [Juan Antonio Breña Moral](https://answers.ros.org/users/464/juan-antonio-bre%C3%B1a-moral/) on 2012-01-22**:
I read in the tutotial about navigation stack: http://www.ros.org/wiki/navigation that it is necessary to use tf messages but you didn't say anithing about it. Tell me your experince

**Comment by [Juan Antonio Breña Moral](https://answers.ros.org/users/464/juan-antonio-bre%C3%B1a-moral/) on 2012-01-22**:
I read in the tutotial about navigation stack: http://www.ros.org/wiki/navigation that it is necessary to use tf messages but you didn't say anithing about it. Tell me your experince.